# Is there any guide of Debian original packaging?

Tags: debian, packages

I feel it like a big mess with the debhelper.  The most info from google on Debian packaging is about to create a Debian package for already existing source packages, or Debian-ize  around Makefile etc.

I have a package say xyz-0.1, contains only shell scripts with no Makefile at all.  Well it should be easy to create a Debian package of it, but I'm stuck with the following error,

```
$ dh_make --createorig
...
$ cat debian/rules
...
build: 

binary: 
    (There's nothing to do with build, because xyz-0.1 contains only shell scripts)

$ debuild
...
dpkg-genchanges: error: cannot read files list file: No such file or directory
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genchanges gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1340:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

(debhelper 7.4.15ubuntu1)

Though, create an empty file `debian/files' will resolve this problem, but it should not be the correct way.

Generally say, is there some guide, comprehensive tutorials on how to use debhelper around original Debian packages?

Comment: For advice on Debian packaging, see the new Ubuntu Q&A site http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference guide to Debian packages is the [Debian Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) (`/usr/share/doc/maint-guide/`). In addition to that, the `dh_*` man pages document the build automation. The [Debian Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) (`/usr/share/doc/debian-policy/`) and [Debian Developer's Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/index.en.html) (`/usr/share/doc/developers-reference/`) have additional advice.

**ADDED:** With current stable versions (Debian lenny, Ubuntu 10.04) of `debhelper`, the default `debian/rules` file has been simplified to two lines, and things mostly work automatically:

```
%:
    dh $@
```

If something doesn't work, investigate by looking at the source of `/usr/bin/dh` and seeing what `dh_*` programs it invokes. The `--after` and `--remaining` options to `dh` are often helpful when debugging package building.

As for `debian/files`, it's not mandatory unless you've tweaked the build rules. If you want help with that, please post the full sequence of error messages (not just the last line), in the original English (not your retranslation). It may also help to know the version of the `dh-make`, `debhelper` and `devscripts` packages.

Comment: I've fixed the error messages.
Version of debhelper is 7.4.15ubuntu1, and the other two's version is unknown (null).

Comment: @谢继雷: Normally something would create `debian/files` as part of the build rules. If you still need help with this, you should post your whole build rules and the whole output of `debuild`.

Comment: @谢继雷: If you don't have the `dh-make` and `devscripts` packages, where do the `dh_make` and `debuild` commands come from?

Comment: The rules is simple, it just redefines the `build' and `binary' target as empty. Because there's nothing to do in build, and the default `binary' target does too much unnecessary jobs. 

The problem is resolved after I added dh_prep, dh_gencontrol, and dh_builddeb to the `binary' target. That's based on a try-and-see method, which isn't so strict to the Debian as a whole.  The documentations you mentioned don't cover on original Debian packages  (which means the package is only for Debian) too much, and I think maybe I should write a Makefile instead, and then Debianize it around.

Comment: @谢继雷: `dh_make` creates a `debian/rules` that works. If you don't have a makefile, comment out the lines that call `$(MAKE)` (with recent versions of the tools, there aren't any). Just don't remove the `dh_*` unless you know what you're doing.